# xaml get selected view in ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, windows-store-apps

I want to get selected item in listview. But I want to get not binded item, i want to get the view, that is selected. So in my case:

```
 <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <local:MyCustomUserControl BindedItem="{Binding}"/> 
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

I want to get MyCustomUserControl object, that is selected now. Thanks, and sorry if something   similar was asked before.

Comment: Does the answer worked for you?

Comment: i`ll check few hours later

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the underlying container i.e. `ListViewItem` using `ItemContainerGenerator` and from that you can get your control by traversing `VisualTree`.

**First** give `x:Name` to your ListView so that you can access it from code behind using that name:

```
<ListView x:Name="listView">
   ...
</ListView>
```

**Second**, get container from `ItemContainerGenerator` and traverse VisualTree to get your child UserControl:

```
var listViewItem = listView.ItemContainerGenerator
                    .ContainerFromItem(listView.SelectedItem);
var customControl = FindChildControl<MyCustomUserControl>(listViewItem);
```

where `FindChildControl` is helper method to traverse Visual Tree:

```
    private T FindChildControl<T>(DependencyObject control)
                                   where T : DependencyObject
    {
        T foundChild = null;
        int childNumber = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(control);
        for (int i = 0; i < childNumber; i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(control, i);
            if (child != null && child is T)
                foundChild = (T)child;
            else
                foundChild = FindChildControl<T>(child);
        }
        return foundChild;
    }
```

---

**Note:** If using using a Windows Store App in Windows 8.1, [ItemContainerGenerator will return `null` if you have not set an `ItemsPanel`](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/4738dfeb-8c45-4bf8-a624-20d4544070b7/windows-81-itemcontainergeneratorcontainerfromitem-returns-null). Instead, use the same method directly on the control. In the example below, `listView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem` would instead be `listView.ContainerFromItem`.

Comment: ItemContainerGenerator is not found. Sorry, i forget to say: i am writing windows store app.

Comment: I updated the answer to note the changes in Windows 8.1. They deprecated use of `ItemContainerGenerator` in most cases. See the note for further explanation.

Comment: @Nate - Thanks for the update but I couldn't test it since I doesn't have Windows 8.1 at my disposal.

Comment: @Boris - Can you please validate it at your end if it works for you now?

Comment: Sorry, that doesnt work, FindChildControl method always return null.

Comment: I used this. listViewItem = senderListView.ContainerFromItem(senderListView.SelectedIndex) as ListViewItem;
But it returns null. Please help me.